# Types of verb: State, Action, Event

Tags: grammar

Here [https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verbs-types] I read:

A verb refers to an action, event or state.

I **cleaned** the room as quickly as possible. [Action verb]

I don’t **know** the name of the street. [State verb]

Four people **died** in the crash. **Event verb???**

> Will this be called **Event verb**?

Answer (score 1):

"Die" belongs a special category of situation type, called the 'achievement verbs'. An achievement verb occurs punctually and occurs at a point in time. It rarely occurs in the present tense, unless it used in a narrative or caption.

The situation type is sometimes called 'aktionsart' or 'lexical aspect'. See also our tag wiki on [aspect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info).

[image]